# HTML CSS & Bootstrap navbar search width / customization

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Struggling with bootstrap / styling. I have created a navbar with a searchbox and some buttons.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to customize the width of the searchbar itself. I could set a fixed width, but I would like to make use of the grid system if possible so that it is responsive.

id like the search bar to be a bit longer than whatever it is defaulting to.
Perhaps the  width being auto screws things up? im not sure.

*I also have a Bootstrap-Select in this fiddle, but for some reason it wont show up (I did add a cdn reference for it.. oh well)

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uaLj1n07/2/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="275" style="margin-bottom:5px">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <form action="#" class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" id="searchForm">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search..." name="searchTerms" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default-grey btn-sm"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                                <select class="selectpicker show-tick " id="searchDate" name="searchDate" data-style="btn btn-default-grey btn-sm" data-width="fit">
                                    <option id="anytime" value="anytime">Any Time</option>
                                    <option data-divider="true"></option>
                                    <option id="30days" value="30days">Last 30 Days</option>
                                    <option id="60days" value="60days">Last 60 Days</option>
                                    <option id="90days" value="30days">Last 90 Days</option>
                                </select>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-link">Advanced</button>
                            </span>
        </div>
      </form>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div class="form-group">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil adjust-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Some Button
          </a>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: you are working with col-sm classes which are used for small view port devices like mobile, if you are working on desktop then use col-md or col-lg classes. the select control is hidden because of selectpicker class which sets display as none.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `min-width` of the search box like this:

```
.form-control.input-sm { 
    min-width: 300px;
}
```

I forked your code and created a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/bxqj3q8g/